# Windows Server Essentials: Server can be pinged, but domain not found

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to set up a small test domain using Parallels Desktop VMs.
I have a freshly installed 180 day demo of Windows Server 2016 Essentials, which has been through the wizard setup procedure and has all current updates. It is the DC, it has a static IP address, DNS is running.
I have a Windows 10 Enterprise client, with the DNS server manually set to the IP of the Windows Server 2016 Essentials box.
DHCP is being handled currently by Parallels.
I CAN ping the server.

However, trying to join the domain results in `An Active Directory Domain Controller ... could not be contacted.` error. I have tried all caps, all lower case, and the mixed case shown in Active Directory Domains and Trusts on the server.

I have also tried using `http://DOMAIN/connect`, which results in a `Can't reach this page` error.

I have verified that the network connection on the server is a Domain Network, and I have turned off the firewall for domain networks.

I had the same issues with a Windows Server 2019 Essentials install.

I assume I am doing something wrong in the configuration, especially since I don't have much experience configuring domains. But that's exactly why I chose Essentials. I just need to be able to test some PowerShell Remoting behavior with 5 or so connected clients, and then only for a week or so.

So, is there something obvious I am missing? Is a Windows Server demo not actually useful for joining a client? In which case, what IS it useful for, since clients joining the domain is what Windows Server is for?

UPDATE: When I use TESTDOMAIN.local as the domain name, I immediately get the `An Active Directory Domain Controller ... could not be contacted.` error. But if I use TESTDOMAIN instead, I get a user name and password prompt and then a DNS error. Suggesting that the DNS server IS being reached.

UPDATE 2: I did a fresh install of Windows Server 2019 Essentials, and addressed things in this order...
1: Activated demo license
2: Installed all updates
3: Set static IP address (I did NOT set the DNS server to this static IP, I set it to 8.8.8.8)
4: Add DNS role
5: Add AD Domain Services role
6: Promote to DC
7: Verified that DNS has an entry under the server name for the domain.

Still getting the same issues. I do notice that the network did NOT change to a Domain network, so I changed it manually in the registry and rebooted. Still issues. So I turned off the firewall completely for Domain networks and rebooted again. Still issues.

I am at a loss.

UPDATE 3: I have now set the NIC on the server to use itself as the primary DNS and 8.8.8.8 as secondary, and the workstation uses the IP of the DC. On the DC I can ping DOMAIN.local, on the workstation that fails. But, I can reach web sites on the workstation, even though DNS is ONLY set to the IP of the DC. And the DC is now using 8.8.8.8 as the secondary, so it seems the workstation IS using the DC as the DNS, and DNS IS using 8.8.8.8 to resolve web site names. So, DNS on the DC is not properly configured somehow. But how? And what is the fix?

UPDATE 4: I added DHCP to the DC, and I set both VMs to use Host Only network, then configured the VM host NOT to provide DHCP services for host only networks. After a Reboot I am getting an IP of 169.254.###.###, which is not the range I set in DHCP. So it seems I am not reaching my DHCP server on the DC, or I have something configured wrong with the VM host. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone facing a similar issue, the source of the problem was having a secondary DNS assigned during DC promotion. The network should be limited to only a primary DNS, and that DNS should be the IP of the server itself. Then you can add the DC and DNS roles and promote the server to DC, at which point the domain will be added to DNS. After that you can add a secondary DNS server.